# Why one badge is acting differently than the others in media 991 on ruby on rails 5?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this piece of code that when in 767px to 991 moves to the middle of the tab. Is the one next to *All Contacts* but the other 3 act perfectly fine.

```
Here is the code:

  <div class="col-md-3">

          <div class="list-group">
            <!-- set active links-->
            <% active = params[:group_id] == nil ? 'active' : '' %>

            <%= link_to contacts_path, class: "list-group-item #{active}" 
do %>
              All Contacts**<span class="badge"><%= Contact.count %> 
</span>**         
            <% Group.all.each do |group| %>
            <% active = params[:group_id].to_i == group.id ? 'active' : '' 
 %>
            <%= link_to contacts_path(group_id: group.id), class: "list- 
 group-item #{active}" do %>
             <%= group.name %><span class="badge"><%= group.contacts.count 
    %></span>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>

          </div>

    application.scss
```

> ```
>   * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
>   *
>   *= require_tree .
>   *= require_self
>
>   *= require jasny-bootstrap.min
>
>   */
>
>   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
>   @import "bootstrap";
>
>   body {
>       padding-top: 70px;
>       background: #eee;
>  }
>
>  .navbar {
>   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0 2px 0;
>   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0 2px 0;
>   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0 2px 0;
> }
> .navbar .navbar-brand {
>   font-weight: bold;
>   letter-spacing: -1px;
>   font-size: 20px;
>   color: white;
> ```
>
> };
>
> ```
> .navbar-right {    
>   margin-right: 0;
> ```
>
> }
>      .btn .btn-default{
>         margin-top: 5;
>      }
>
> .table tbody>tr>td.middle {
>         vertical-align: middle;
>      }
>
> .media {
>          padding: 10px 0;
>    }
>
> .media img, .fileinput .thumbnail, .thumbnail img {
>     border-radius: 50%;
>      }
>
> .media-left {
>         padding: 0 20px;
>      }
>
> .media-heading {
>         color: #dd5638;
>         margin-bottom: 10px;
>     }
>
> .media-body {
>         padding-top: 15px;
>     }
>
> .btn-circle {
>       width: 30px;
>       height: 30px;
>       text-align: center;
>       padding: 6px 0;
>       font-size: 12px;
>       line-height: 1.428571429;
>       border-radius: 15px;
>     }

```
   > this my .scss  file, in the scss i have just a couple lines but the .js is not modified<

Can you help?
```

Comment: Would be good to see jsfiddle or codepen that reproduces the issue

Comment: Since you're working with media queries we would at the very least need to see the css and/or javascript related to the tabs.